# dcm4che: occasional unexpected message ID in DIMSE RSP?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I'm a newbie in programming with dcm4che2 libraries and I'm writing a simple program to query a PACS server, by setting Query/Retrieve Level to Patient/Series/Image.
The code is very simple and, in some cases, it works fine:

```
  dcmqr.setCalledAET("AET_REMOTE", true);
  dcmqr.setRemoteHost("aa.bb.cc.dd");
  dcmqr.setRemotePort(xxxx);
  dcmqr.getKeys();

  dcmqr.setDateTimeMatching(true);
  dcmqr.setCFind(true);
  dcmqr.setCGet(false);
  dcmqr.configureTransferCapability(true);
  dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.IMAGE);

  dcmqr.addMatchingKey(new int[]{Tag.PatientName},sPatientName);
  dcmqr.addMatchingKey(new int[]{Tag.Modality},sModality);  
  dcmqr.addMatchingKey(new int[]{Tag.AccessionNumber},sAccession);
  dcmqr.addMatchingKey(new int[]{Tag.SeriesNumber},sSeriesNumber);
  dcmqr.addReturnKey(new int[]{Tag.SeriesDescription});
  dcmqr.addReturnKey(new int[]{Tag.StudyDescription});
  dcmqr.addReturnKey(new int[]{Tag.PatientBirthDate});
  dcmqr.addReturnKey(new int[]{Tag.PatientSex});

  List<DicomObject> result = null;

  try{
    dcmqr.start();
    dcmqr.open();
    result = dcmqr.query();
    dcmqr.stop();
    dcmqr.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      ...
  }
```

However in some cases (and whenever I set Query/Retrieve Level to "Image"), the query() method fails ("unexpected message ID in DIMSE RSP") and an A-Abort command is thrown, as reported below:

```
...

[main] INFO org.dcm4che2.net.PDUEncoder - AET_REMOTE(1) << 3:C-FIND-RQ[pcid=1,   prior=0
        cuid=xyz/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
        ts=xyz/Implicit VR Little Endian]

[AE_TITLE_X] INFO org.dcm4che2.net.PDUDecoder - AET_REMOTE(1) >> 2:C-FIND-RSP[
pcid=1, status=0H cuid=xyz/Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND]

[main] INFO org.dcm4che2.tool.dcmqr.DcmQR - Send Query Request #3/15 using .../Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND:
(0008,0052) CS #6 [IMAGE] Query/Retrieve Level
(0008,0060) CS #2 [CT] Modality
(0010,0010) PN #12 [xxx^yyyy] PatientÆs Name
(0020,000D) UI #42 [x.y.z.zyx...] Study Instance UID
(0020,000E) UI #56 [y.x.z.zyx...] Series Instance UID

[AE_TITLE_X] WARN org.dcm4che2.net.Association - unexpected message ID in DIMSE RSP:
(0000,0002) UI #28 [x.y.z.zax...] Affected SOP Class UID
(0000,0100) US #2 [32800] Command Field
(0000,0120) US #2 [2] Message ID Being Responded To
(0000,0800) US #2 [257] Command Data Set Type
(0000,0900) US #2 [0] Status

[AE_TITLE_X] INFO org.dcm4che2.net.PDUEncoder - AET_REMOTE(1) << A-ABORT[source=0,       reason=0]
[AE_TITLE_X] INFO org.dcm4che2.net.Association - AET_REMOTE(1): close    Socket[addr=/aa.bb.cc.dd,port=xxx,localport=yyy]

[main] INFO org.dcm4che2.net.PDUEncoder - AET_REMOTE(1) << 4:C-FIND-RQ[pcid=1, prior=0
cuid=.../Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - FIND
    ts=.../Implicit VR Little Endian]
[main] WARN org.dcm4che2.net.Association - unable to send P-DATA-TF in state: Sta1
```

Indeed, I can't understand what does this error mean and figure out a solution. 
I guess it's a communication issue..
Do anyone could help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logging indicates that you've made query request #3, then received the response for query request #2. If the listener is now expecting a response for 3, then it will throw an exception because it has received a message ID for message 2.

If you are looping over the query call to do this, you could try specifying the instances as a list instead:

```
addMatchingKey( new int[] { Tag.SeriesInstanceUID }, "uid1\\uid2\\uid3" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure to understand: I'm making a query at Image level just once, and I was expecting to get back a list of images (for a specific Series Instance UID). Should I increase the listener waiting time, in order to catch the next RSP message properly? On the contrary, may I catch the exception and manage it in a better way?

Comment: From your logs, it looks like you are making query #3 (AET_REMOTE(1) << 3) before you're getting a response from previous query #2 (AET_REMOTE(1) >> 2). As a result, your listener is now expecting message id 3, not 2. You may need to turn on the DEBUG logs and look at your timing and what Association you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I overlooked that SeriesInstanceUID, is not listed among keys at composite object instance level. I prefer switching to SOPInstanceUID. The problems is solved.